# Continue execution after page redirect (javascript-chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension to check some values or click on a button in the content of the chrome browser page when it's completely loaded.
After that redirect to a URL and do again.
I have a 100000 URLs and I want to check them all.
I tried some example and load a new URL address after that read data or click on the button, then changed the page location, but after that extensions don't continue and stop till I click on the extension icon in the browser. how can I implement a loop? thanks

Comment: This seems like an odd function for an extension. And with that many urls is going to take a long time to load anyway. Regardless you want to look at run it this in your background js file rather then the front end that loads when you click on the extension

Comment: If you have a firm understanding of the [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) then it'll be trivial to make such a loop.